# How to make my fig tree better?

Tags: figs

Someone gifted me a fig tree at the beginning of winter (because I had just started to get interested in gardening).
I think it was in a greenhouse before it ended up **inside** my not-so-sunny apartment.

I assume it started to grow like crazy again because of the warm temperature.

[image: Looking good]

But then, I assume the lack of sunlight made it suffer.

Almost all leaves fell, and branches dried out.
Only 2 green branches remain, but they grew weirdly (I believe in search for sunlight), and the leaves don't seem healthy (I left it outside now).

[image: Looking sad]

[image]

[image]

Does someone know what I can do to make it healthier ?
And if someone knows what I might have done wrong, I'm interested too.

Also this might be of importance:

- I had a gnat infestation almost all winter.
- I live in the very North of France.

Comment: The fig wants to be outside in a warmer location ,so I think the practical thing is to get a different plant.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I'd prefer not to let it die though, if there's still something I can do. Plus, summer is coming, so temperature won't be an issue for the time being.